# How to push the code changes files in gitlab through terminal

Tags: git, gitlab

I had done commited those changed files but i can't able to push the code into the gitalb through terminal. Can you please help me. Thank you advance.

Comment: Show us what command and what error you got?

Answer (score 5):

I hope you have committed the code properly using this command:

> git commit -m "commit message"

Now check your remote whether it points to the repository in the GitLab
using :

> git remote -v

It may show you something like this if remote is present:

```
sample-group    http://10.212.0.147:8888/shaggy/myProject.git (fetch)
sample-group    http://10.212.0.147:8888/shaggy/myProject.git (push)
origin  http://10.212.0.147:8888/shaggy/myProject.git (fetch)
origin  http://10.212.0.147:8888/shaggy/myProject.git (push)
```

If the remote location of GitLab is not present then add the remote using the command :

> git remote add origin **your_GitLabs_repository_URL**

Again check the remote

> git remote -v

Now you are ready to push the repository to the GitLab repoisoty
using te command

> git push origin master

For your reference https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/README.html

Comment: Happy coding..!! Please upvote and mark as answer if it was useful and correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Github account already within then project but you want to add the code to Gitlab without losing github remote then

Step-1: Commit the code

Step-2: Go to gitlab and get the remote url for your project

Step-3: Go to your project and start the terminal and then type in the following comnnand

git remote add origin1

Step-4: Push the code

git push origin1 master